# Web push notifications

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am making a website and one of the features is that whenever a contract is nearing its end, the user should be notified about it. So I was looking for a way to notify users and I found out about push notifications.
Now, there are lots of things written about it. I heard a lot about Google Cloud Messaging, Firebase Cloud Messaging and Service Workers.
Now the thing is that my website will probably be on an Intranet. So maybe I won't be able to use GCM/FCM.

But I have a few questions regarding GCM, FCM and Service-Workers:

1. Why do I need FCM/GCM?
2. What is the difference between FCM and Service Workers?
3. Is there a way to push notifications even if the browser is closed?
4. Because my website is on an Intranet, is there another way to push notifications to the users?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why do I need FCM/GCM?**

- You may check [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-FCM-Firebase-Cloud-Messaging) the features of FCM.

  - Notification payload: 4KB, Message payload: 2KB. Note that the notification includes device and app information too.
  - Stores 100 notification/messages per device if the device is offline.
  - Stores notification/messages for 30 days if the device is offline, and deleted them all one this period is over and the device is still offline.
  - FCM supports Android and iOS devices, and even chrome web apps. The notifications are sent to iOS devices in this way: App Server -> FCM -> Apple Push Notification Server (APNs) -> iOS device -> App.
  - GCM supports 1 million subscribers while FCM do not have this limitation.
  - Supports programming in C++.
  - Less requirements for coding.

**2. What is the difference between FCM and Service Workers?**

- [Service Worker](https://aarontgrogg.com/blog/2015/07/20/the-difference-between-service-workers-web-workers-and-websockets/) is a background service that handles network requests. Ideal for dealing with offline situations and background syncs or push notifications. Cannot directly interact with the DOM. Communication must go through the Service Worker’s `postMessage` method. Service Workers are pretty perfect for creating offline-first web apps. They let you interact with the server when you can (to fetch new data from the server, or push updated info back to the server), so your app can work regardless of your user’s connectivity.
- While using [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), you can notify a client app that new email or other data is available to sync. You can send notification messages to drive user reengagement and retention. For use cases such as instant messaging, a message can transfer a payload of up to 4KB to a client app.

**3. Is there a way to push notifications even if the browser is closed?**

- Check this thread: [Notifications while browser is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247422/notifications-while-browser-is-closed)

**4. Because my website is on an Intranet, is there another way to push notifications to the users?**

- Unfortunately, I don't see any documentation regarding this.

Hope my answers help you.

Comment: Can you please tell me why can't I do the notifications myself, without using FCM? What are the problems I may run into while trying to do so?